# Clean way to build & update SKU combinations from JSON, keep stock, minimize DB queries?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

My database has records per SKU, giving product options (id's actually, but for clarity I'm showing actual values):

```
---------------------------------------------------------
id       color        size       material          stock
---------------------------------------------------------
1         blue         m          cotton             3
2         blue         s          cotton             5
3         blue         xl         plastic            6
4         white        l          plastic            1
5         white        m          plastic            9
```

I would like to show select boxes for each option that update the others upon change, so you can only select possible combinations (ie. choosing 'plastic' renders white(l+m) and blue(xl) )

I can do this with jQuery/Ajax but that requires queries to the db for every select-box change, rebuilding all other select-boxes. It's mainly the db queries I want to minimize, so I considered building a JSON representation of the above table, cache it, use it for the selects. I'd update the JSON result only when *total* stock changes (which is available from another table with a single query).

The problem is I can not figure out how to do that properly; I'm not very skilled in JS and keep bumping into walls. I'm not even sure it's the right approach, how to get the right ID for the chosen combination posted back etc. Yet I'm quite convinced this is a rather common problem, or so it seems. But searching surprisingly did not give me similar problems; just a lot 'one select updates the other through ajax' info.

So my question is: how would one tackle this problem efficiently?

**EDIT: Some additional info:** 
this is for a product detail page where we only show the options (SKU's) for that single 'master' product.

I also found this [cascading](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=26338) approach which is close. Problem is I can not copy that approach since my 'blue' or 'white' is not unique, or so it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central question here is, how many SKUs do you have?  If you have a large number of SKUs for any given single option (such as blue) then you can't simply use brute force and send all of the SKUs for any given combination of dropdowns to the client.

In fact, you probably can't even cache them on the server that way.  It would not be efficient.  There are probably too many combinations, and too many of them have too many SKUs.

So I'd go a step farther and suggest that, if you're hitting your database for searches, the problem is that *you're hitting your database for searches* when what you need is indexed search (such as Lucene/Solr).  Yes, sending huge numbers of searches to the database can become a problem.  An indexed search server can take huge numbers of searches, and has internal cache, and it will spit out the results very fast.

I should add that when it comes to "live" data like inventory, now you need to hit the database, as it's usually not feasible to keep reindexing the search engine to keep up with changes in inventory.  But there you can build a very efficient query based on an individual SKU, or a small number of them.

Comment: Thanks - the number of SKU combinations is not very high and by definition per product. A product will potentially have about 10-15 SKU's max. Most will be regular sizes and a couple of colors (think printed T-shirts) So something like Solr seems overkill at this point I think.

Comment: Fair enough.  You say that "potentially" each will have 10-15 SKUs max.  You need to be sure about this.  If that is the case, my recommendation is to break the problem down into small pieces.  Mock up a JSON response for 15 SKUs, put that JSON into a simple text file, and try calling it to make sure you can read the JSON data successfully.  Then code a page that reads this and populates the dropdowns.  Make another mocked JSON file that returns only five responses when color is set to "blue".  So try to simplify as much as you can, and code little pieces at a time.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, does that mean that the page in question is for a single product only?  I didn't get that from the original post. I thought you were talking about a page that might show SKUs for many products.  If it does, then we're now talking about 10-15 SKUs times the number of products returned.

Comment: Sorry for all the unclarity; yes - we're talking single product detail page showing one product with it's SKU variants, which will mostly consist of just color and size. The "potentially"  is because I imagine there will be products with different variations eventually. This is purely for ordering the specific combo of that specific product; not for site-wide searches etc.

Comment: OK.  I was wrong when I said you needed a second mocked JSON file for when color is blue.  You just need one that represents all the values for a given SKU.  Your page calls this on first loading.  Then it needs to recognize when a dropdown has changed, and then rescan the JSON data, get only the values specified by all of the dropdowns, and then update all of the dropdowns.  But the first step is defining a mocked JSON file, and being sure you can read and parse that, and then do the initial population of the dropdowns.

Comment: Also you might want a server-side cache to hold the values for a given product.  You could define it to hold the values for up to 1000 products.  If the limit is reached, the oldest entry (or maybe the one with the fewest calls) is pushed out and replaced by the new one.  This can also dramatically lower the DB calls, but again, this is server side and not directly related to your question.

Comment: That brings me back to my problem :) I'm not sure how to construct the JSON data so it is easily parsed while maintaining the unique id so I know which combo has been chosen... I know how to create multidimensional arrays but I'm confused on this one.

Comment: Go to www.json.org and get json2.js.  It has a stringify method.  Just pass your Javascript data into it and it will give you a JSON string.  Example:

    var e = {
        prod: [1, 2, [3, 4]],
        x: "a"
    }
    var s = JSON.stringify(e);

Note that you have to comment out the first line in json2.js before using it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4592/discussion-between-dnuttle-and-matt)